# Django : value has the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD) but it is an invalid date

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm working with Nepali date and the following date is correct but django don't let me run the query.

```
search_range = Trans.objects.filter(tr_date__gte='2077-04-01', tr_date__lte='2077-04-32')
```

I've following code which is working fine if i give date upto 2077-04-30. But according to Nepali calender 4th month has 32 days. When i try to run the query with day 32 django returns following error.

```
ValidationError at /trans/list/search/

['“2077-04-32” value has the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD) but it is an invalid date.']

Request Method:     GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/trans/list/search/
Django Version:     3.1
Exception Type:     ValidationError
Exception Value:    

['“2077-04-32” value has the correct format (YYYY-MM-DD) but it is an invalid date.']
```

How can i get the data within mentioned range? Any suggestion is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not just use tr_date__lt='2077-05-01' i.e. just less than 5/1 - I personally have never heard of there being 32 days in any month, but if you just filter for less than 5/1 won't it have the same result?

Comment: Thank you so much E.J. Brennan. The way you've suggested solved my issue. We use Nepali calender which has BS date insted of AD. There are upto 32 days in a month. Total days in a month are calculated based on the movement of the Moon.